# Access Azure Storage Via a Registered App Using a Certificate

Tags: java, azure

I'm new to Azure and I'm struggling to get a simple demo working.

What I'm trying to do is access a file in an Azure storage account using a Java client that accesses Azure via a registered app using a certificate. (I have to do it this way for a job I'll be doing at work.)

This is what I did in Azure (accepting defaults for everything):

- create storage account `wemsa`
- create container `wemco` inside `wemsa`
- upload (a small) file 'spiral.jpeg' into container `wemco`
- create app registration `wemapp`
- upload certificate 'azure.crt' into `wemapp`

Then I returned to the container `wemco` and:

- granted role '*Storage Blob Data Contributor*' to `wemapp`

My Java client does this:

```
ClientCertificateCredential credentials = new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId("11518eab-7b5a-493c-8d12-27731fe51341")
        .tenantId("4b106bc5-7518-4f86-a259-f5726d124732")
        .pemCertificate("azure.pem")
        .build();

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .credential(credentials)
        .endpoint("https://wemsa.blob.core.windows.net/")
        .buildClient();

BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("wemco");

blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("spiral.jpeg").downloadToFile("/home/william/blob.jpeg");
```

This code doesn't work - it hangs at the last line. An empty file, `blob.jpeg`, is created on my local machine. There is no exception thrown and nothing is written to the console, so I have no clue to indicate what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating to very latest versions of maven dependencies for:

- `com.azure:azure-storage-blob`, and
- `com.azure:azure-identity`